# SVG Path mouseover behaving incorrectly in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

The mouseover behavior in Internet Explorer seems to depend on what values I give for the transform attribute, and the magnitude of the points in the d attribute.

In the provided example, in Internet Explorer, the red triangle exhibits the mouseover behavior only when the pointer is within the painted area of the path element. The blue triangle's mouseover behavior triggers when the mouse moves  inside the bounding box of the triangle's path.

This issue is not reproduceable in Chrome and Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/3591mj2o/7/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="d3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #path1 {
        fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }

    #path2 {
        fill: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }

    svg {
        border-style: dotted;
        border-width: 2px;

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg height="200" width="150">
  <path id="path1" transform="translate(0,0)scale(1)" d="M75 0 L0 200 L150 200 Z" />
</svg>
<svg height="200" width="150">
  <path id="path2" transform="translate(0,0)scale(1000)" d="M.075 0 L0 .2 L.15 .2 Z" />
</svg>
<script type="text/javascript" >
d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", function (d) {
    var selection = d3.select(this)
    selection.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0.25);
});
d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseout", function () {
    var selection = d3.select(this)
    selection.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0.7);
});
</script>
</body>
```

I can't think of a good explanation as to why this is happening. I also can't find a way to get the blue triangle working as expected in Internet Explorer.

Comment: This is pretty similar, however the workaround in the accepted answer isn't feasible for my use case. The example in the question includes the "workaround" version to help isolate the issue.

Comment: The cause is the same - a bug in IE with mouseover detection when the element has a transform.  The only workaround I know of is the one in the other question, and which you discovered yourself.

Comment: I have posted an answer on the other question, and linked back to this question for further context. I don't agree that the questions are duplicates, as the author of the other question did not need to use the transform.